# Selector for a list-item containing a child element with a specified attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to display a particular item in a list based on a specific href value within an `<a>` tag.

```
 <ul id="images">
    <li class="other-image" style="display: none;">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example.com/page.html">
            <img src="http://www.test.com/home/pic.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="other-image" style="display: none;">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.exmaple.com/index.html">
            <img src="http://www.example-image.com/image.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="other-image" style="display: none;">
        <a target="_blank" href="http://www.example1.com/test">
            <img src="http://www.example-image1.com/image1.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#images").find("li").fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
});
```

For example I want to display an item where `href="http://www.exmaple.com/index.html"`. I wouldn't want to use index instead because this item could have a different index as more items are added/removed from the list. I've tried writing the selector several different ways (below) to only select a list item with this a specific href value with no success.

Attempt #1:

```
$("#images").find("li").filter($("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']")).fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

Attempt #2:

```
$("#CCCImages").find($("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']")).fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

Attempt #3:

```
$("#CCCImages").children($("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']")).fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for being a new user and actually trying to solve the problem yourself first before asking

Answer (score 2):

Attempt 1 fails because you are looking for an anchor tag in a list of lis. It is not looking at the children.

Attempt 2 fails since you are not fading the li

Attempt 3, anchor is not a child.

There are tons of ways to do it.

One is

```
$("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']").closest("li").fadeIn();
```

Comment: If you want to do it from the other direction. You want to use [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery selectors, and particularly after invoking [DOM traversal] methods, you must be mindful of the current matched set when calling methods on the jQuery object. As an example, to break down your first attempt,

```
$("#images")   // Targeted set is only the <ul>
  .find("li")  // Only the 3 <li> elements
  .filter($("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']")) // matches nothing.
  .fadeIn()
  .delay(10000)
  .fadeOut();
```

The [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) examines each `<li>` and checks if it is also an `<a>`, so they all fail and are left out. As the docs point out:

> The supplied selector is tested against each element; all elements matching the selector will be included in the result.

Tweaking the above, we can easily correct the filter to be a little more effective. First, target the desired `<li>`s: `$("#images li")`

Then filter the results using [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/), limiting your result-set to those which have an anchor link matching your criterion: `.has("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']")`

And finally, do your fading.

```
$("#images li")
  .has("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']")
  .fadeIn()
  .delay(10000)
  .fadeOut();
```

---

Of course, if you're curious, the `filter` method can also be leveraged in a useful way to accomplish this. There is an overloaded variant of the method which accepts a function to use for filtering. In this case, the usage below is functionally equivalent to using `has`, but more verbose.

```
$("#images li").filter(function() {
    return $(this)
             .find("a[href='http://www.exmaple.com/index.html']")
             .length > 0;
})
.fadeIn(); // etc.
```